# How do I resolve this lighting bug in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

This lighting issue in the top right corner of the picture provided is very annoying and not very good looking the light is supposed to look like all of the other ones around the scene but randomly some of them will appear like this. Does anyone know why and how to fix it. The lights are just spotlights shinning onto a place that is parallel to the source direction.

[image: Lighting Bug]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thats because you have only 4 "pixel" lights. Go to Quality settings and increase that number :)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Have been trying to figure this out for a while now.